# Passing an Array to a structure in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct, c89

In order to fill a structure with integers (to then be passed on further in the program) I thought the following would work:

```
main() {
struct songs {int pitch[5], length[5];} songs[4];
int i[5]={1,22,23,14,52};
int k=0;
 songs[0].pitch=i;      
 for (k=0; k<5; k++) printf("%d\n",songs[0].pitch[k]);
}
```

however this comes up with an error "incompatible types in assignment"

if I dont however pass this array to the structure, using the following:

```
main() {
int i[5]={1,22,23,14,52};
int k=0;   
 for (k=0; k<5; k++) printf("%d\n",i[k]);
}
```

it compiles and will display the content of the array.

I realise there is probably a simple fix to this, but any help would be brilliant!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Added the C89 tag because you're relying on the "default to int" rule which was removed in C99.

Comment: Arrays cannot be assigned like that in C. You need to loop to copy each element of an array to another array or use `memcpy` as suggested in the answers

Answer (score 6):

C89 does not allow you to assign an array to another array. Here's the relevant bit from C99, but the text is much the same in C89 with the exception of the mention of the C99 only type `_Bool`. (I only have paper copies of C89)

[image: Simple Assignment section]

Arrays don't fit any of these conditions -- they aren't arithmetic types, they aren't of structure or union type, and they're not pointers<sup>1</sup>. Therefore you can't use the assignment operator on them.

You can, however, use `memcpy`. If you replace this line:

```
songs[0].pitch=i;
```

with this line:

```
memcpy(songs[0].pitch, i, sizeof(i));
```

you'll get the behavior you expect. (After including `<string.h>` first of course)

---

<sup>1</sup> Technically speaking 6.3.2.1/3 says that the array is converted into an *rvalue* pointer before it is seen by `operator=`, but such an assignment is still prohibited because 6.5.16/2 requires that the left side of an assignment be an *lvalue*.

Comment: correct me if i am wrong, but you are telling him to copy 4 bytes, to address `i`. `sizeof(i)` is 4, since it is only a pointer; even if you would say `sizeof *i`, that would still be 4, since `*i` is an `int`

Comment: afaik, in C, when you declare an array, that variable is actually a pointer to the preceeding type name. it points, indeed, to the first entry of "the array", but nothing "is an array". afaik, there is no such thing in C. it`s only a pointer to a block of memory.

Comment: @Hame: No, that's not how it works. An array is implicitly convertible to a pointer to its first element, but that doesn't mean that it is a pointer to its first element. http://ideone.com/MvwVVc

Comment: i've tried your code. it works. my bad. now why did i know that...?

Comment: "Arrays don't fit any of these conditions -- [...] and they're not pointers." -- they are in this case, arrays undergo lvalue conversion as the left hand side operand of assignment. What's violated is the requirement of 6.5.16 p2 that they need to be modifiable lvalues (what they aren't after lvalue conversion). (At least for C99, array decay was different somewhere in C89, don't remember exactly.)

Comment: @mafso Do you have a standard reference for why that conversion occurs? This section is pretty specific in saying the actual types rather than types after conversion. If you've got a reference I'll update the answer.

Comment: 6.3.2.1 p3 seems to indicate this, though I'm not entirely sure. You're right in that it doesn't make sense to interpret the constraints you quote as referring to lvalue-converted types. So both constraints seem violated.

Comment: @mafso: Added a footnote. Does that look OK?

Comment: Your last comment already convinced me enough to upvote :). Either way, it doesn't matter, the constraints apply before lvalue conversion, just as you said. It doesn't matter which constraint is violated first and whether there is some conversion if the code is invalid with or without it.

Answer (score 2):

Due to the way C handles arrays you can't assign to one like that. You need to copy over the values, either individually or via [`memcpy`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memcpy) (or similar functions). Example:

```
for (k=0; k<5; k++){
    songs[0].i[k] = i[k];
}
```

or:

```
memcpy(songs[0].i, i, sizeof i);
```

Note that `memcpy` requires you to include `<string.h>`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to copy the array elements individually. Also the main function really should return an int.

```
int main( void ) {
struct songs {int pitch[5], length[5];} songs[4];
int i[5]={1,22,23,14,52};
int qq, k=0;
 for( qq=0; qq<5; qq++) {
   songs[0].pitch[qq]=i[qq];      
 }
 for (k=0; k<5; k++) printf("%d\n",songs[0].pitch[k]);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Billy ONeal- sure, and real code shouldn't be littered with magic numbers either. But I think this is fine to demonstrate the concept.

Comment: Sure, that's why I didn't -1. But thought the comment was worthwhile nonetheless :)

Answer (score 0):

C does not let you copy arrays into arrays. You have to do an element by element copy.

```
    struct songs {int pitch[5], length[5];} songs[4];
    int i[5]={1,22,23,14,52};
    int k=0;
    for (k=0; k<5; k++) songs[0].pitch[k] = i[k];
    for (k=0; k<5; k++) printf("%d\n",songs[0].pitch[k]);
```

Answer (score 0):

when you declare an array, you have 2 options:

```
int * i;     // #1; you do this when you don`t know the size
int i[size]; // #2
```

you can not assign an array to another array.

what you need to do, as others suggested, is to copy all elements of the array one by one:

```
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        songs[0].pitch[j] = i[j];
    }
```

remember that using the index operator, [], is the same as dereferencing the pointer.

even more, when you say `pitch[j]` you actually move the pointer j positions forward and dereference it; like you would be saying `*(pitch+j)`

Answer (score 0):

```
the following, compiles, runs, works.

notice the correction to the declaration of main
notice the addition of #include string.h to support memcpy function
notice the proper return statement at the end

and most importantly,
notice the correct method of copying an array

as a side note:
making the struct tag name and the instance name the same
is very bad programming practice

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    struct songs
    {
        int pitch[5];
        int length[5];
    } songs[4];

    int i[5]={1,22,23,14,52};
    int k=0;
    memcpy( songs[0].pitch, i, sizeof( i ) );
    for (k=0; k<5; k++) 
    {
        printf("%d\n",songs[0].pitch[k]);
    } // end for

    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Problem is here,

```
songs[0].pitch=i;
```

Use int* in the structure, You can't assign an array to another array and name of the structure and the structure object.

This would work.

```
struct Songs {int* pitch, length[5];} songs[4];
```

Comment: That has very different semantics than the code the OP originally posted.